# Compare length batches of data with each other in Siddhi

Tags: wso2, siddhi, stream-analytics

I've defined the input stream below. The Datetime string is like `2010-09-01 06:59:00.000`, the result is a double like `157,382` and the UnixDateTime is in type long like `1283324340111`.

```
define stream HStream(ID int, DateTime String, Result double, UnixDateTime long);
```

I want to make length batches for 100 events that display an average for the `result` column and I want to compare these batches with each other. I want to do this sliding comparison for the next 5 batches (that all include 100 events each). So I want to compare the first batch (0-100 event) to the second batch (101-200), untill the sixth batch (501-600). And I want the second batch to compare untill the 7th batch. What I want to achieve with the comparison is that when 4 or more (from the 5) batches have a batch average result that is all bigger or all smaller than 1 (compared to the average result from the original batch), then I want to log the info about the original batch.

My code is below. The problem I don't know the exact syntax. I've looked at the tutorials and documentation at WSO2 and Siddhi, but I cannot solve the problem.

```
@info(name = 'MovingAverageQuery')
from every e1=HStream, e2=HStream[e1.avg(Result) <= avg(Result))+, e2=HStream[e2[last].avg(Result) <= avg(Result)]
select ID, DateTime, Result, 
avg(Result), UnixDateTime
output last every 100 events
insert into OutputStream;

@sink(type='log', prefix='LOGGER')
define stream OutputStream(Nr ID, DateTime String, Result double, Avg double, UnixDateTime long);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two queries for the requirement, one is to calculate the averages (Average100Query) and other is to compare the averages(IdentifyIncreaseingTrend).

```
@App:name("AverageSequence")
@App:description("Identify the average increase trend")

define stream HStream(ID int, DateTime String, Result double, UnixDateTime long);

@sink(type='log', prefix='LOGGER')
define stream OutputStream(ID int, DateTime String, avgResult double, UnixDateTime long);

@info(name = 'Average100Query')
from HStream#window.lengthBatch(100)
select ID, DateTime, avg(Result) as avgResult, UnixDateTime 
insert into AverageStream;

@info(name='IdentifyIncreaseingTrend')
from every e1=AverageStream, e2=AverageStream[e2.avgResult >= (e1.avgResult + 1)],  e3=AverageStream[e3.avgResult >= (e2.avgResult + 1)],  e4=AverageStream[e4.avgResult >= (e3.avgResult + 1)], e5=AverageStream[e5.avgResult >= (e4.avgResult + 1)]
select e1.ID, e1.DateTime, e1.avgResult, e1.UnixDateTime 
insert into OutputStream;
```

Some of the syntax issues I have noticed is after a calculation is done, such as sum(result) you have to use `as` keyword to name that attribute as `sum(result) as totalResult` . In sequences, you cant use average function as it need to be done for multiple events but you canuse the renamed attribute `totalResult`.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I have implemented your code, but when I run the app I get this error: ````AverageSequence.siddhi - Siddhi AppAverageSequence is in faulty state.````

Comment: I tested in Siddhi Tooling 5.1.0, https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/quick-start/ and it is running

Comment: The app may have not deployed before starting the app. Wait till you see the log, ` Siddhi App AverageSequence successfully deployed.` before starting the siddhi app

Comment: I did something wrong. It was not a error of Siddhi. Thank u for the help. I have another question about the query u wrote. The query u wrote only looks if the avgResult is 1 bigger, can I also put in the same query that it looks for 1 smaller? Or do I have to make a seperate query for that?

Comment: You have to add a separate query for that since you need that check for all 5 consecutive events

Comment: Please feel free to reach the siddhi team on slack. Its is much faster than stack overflow, https://siddhi.io/community/

Comment: Ok, I will do that!